# How to rename or delete android system file like as "mmssms.db"

Tags: android, android-file, smsmanager

I want to hide all SMS inbox in programmatically.
my idea is that rename SMS database to another that android cannot read it and when i want to show them, rename again it to mmssms.db
but i can`t rename it, or even delete it.

```
File fileRename= new File("/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db";
fileRename.renameto(new "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/new_mmssms.db");
```

or even i tried it to delete it:

```
String delCmd= "rm -r " + "/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db";
Rintime runt = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec(delCmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without root access, it's impossible.

Comment: Hi, @agamov, so how i can hide sms inbox ?! do you have any idea?